# Regular expression for digits

Tags: regex

I need help from someone with more regular expression mojo than I. I would like a somewhat efficient RE to find a string containing 8 to 12 digits with zero or more space or hyphen separators within the digits.

I can brute force it but I’m hoping for something more elegant.

Added:

Basically anything like:

123-456-78,
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-1-2,
12345678,
12345 67890

But I don’t want:

0-123456789012,
012345 6789012

(Sorry, editing on iPad)

Comment: Are you looking for a regex for phone numbers? You'll have to define the structure you're looking for and tailor your regex to fit that structure, or what you're demanding is too broad.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That fails for `1   -------          2345678`.

Comment: Basically anything like: 000-000-0000, 0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0, 00000000, 00000 00000, etc. But I don’t want 0-123456789012 or 012345 6789012.

Comment: @Shift4SMS This information should be in your question, not in a comment, but that aside, it is still not clear exactly what you want to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this which looks for a sequence of 8-12 digits with optional space or hyphen:

```
^(\d[\s-]?){8,12}$
```

Comment: To avoid string ending with space or hyphen, a little twist will be `^(\d[\s-]?){7,11}\d$`

Comment: This might be doable. I guess I was overthinking it.